# How pointer passed in Fuction arguments ? With example Program?

Tags: c++, c

I would like to know the flow of pointer in function arguments. Please help me how an below will be executed line by line and its flow,

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main() {

        int i = 97, *p = &i;

        foo(&i); printf("%d ", *p);
    }

    void foo(int *p) {
        int j = 2;

        p = &j;
        printf("%d ", *p);
    }
```

Comment: Program would not compile.

Comment: @haccks why? I don't see any syntax errors here

Comment: A debugger would be the perfect thing to use to see it executed line by line and it's flow.

Comment: Have you compiled it?...probably you will be getting warnings... and better go for a tutorial

Comment: Pointer function arguments do not "flow".

Comment: I think you will see the desired effect when you replace "p=&j" by "*p=j".

Comment: @wolfPack88; No. It will not run fine.

Comment: I believe OP would like to see the result `2 2` rather than `2 97`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should let the compiler see the declaration of `foo()`, before calling it

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int *p); // <<<<<<<<<< Declare your function first!

int main() {

    int i = 97, *p = &i;

    foo(&i); printf("%d ", *p);
}

void foo(int *p) {
    int j = 2;

    p = &j;
    printf("%d ", *p);
}
```

Play with it when you reached **[this stage](http://ideone.com/y01z5b)**.

Inside `foo()`you're just changing `p` on the local stack to point to `j`, not affecting `p` nor `i` from `main`, because `p` has been passed by value (copy).

If you want to change the value of `i` from inside your function, you need to alter it this way :

```
void foo(int *p) {
    *p = 2;
    printf("%d ", *p);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, that's very true, but no answer.

Comment: @Quentin Tried to improve ...

Comment: I hope it didn't come out as rude. I'm a bit uneasy short-circuiting the peer validation and editing people's posts directly... Or can I still just suggest edits ?

Comment: @Quentin _"I hope it didn't come out as rude."_ No, no, no! At least in this case it was absolutely OK and appreciated. I would have rolled back edits otherwise. You're welcome ...